# fail to get procees name (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, user32

i wan to create a program that can get the application name
i can start the program but cant get the program name

```
<br/><br/>
a = Process.Start("calc").Handle<br/>
MsgBox(a)<br/>
MsgBox(Process.GetProcessById(a).ToSt</ br>ring)<br/>
<br/>
```

it show Process with an Id of 1796 is not running, but the program already opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Handle`!=`Id`, and `ToString()` won't give you the process name:

```
Dim a = Process.Start("calc").Id
MsgBox(a)
MsgBox(Process.GetProcessById(a).ProcessName)
```

Displays a process ID in one message box, then "calc" in the next.

If you had Option Strict On, you'd have received a warning already about your mixup between Handle and Id, since `Handle` returns an `IntPtr`, but `GetProcessById` expects an `Integer`.

Comment: oic..
ty for reply my post..
ty <3